# Strange behaviour with angularJS $scope.$parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm have having some trouble accessing a value from the parent scope, and what appears to be some strange behaviour also.

If I log `$scope.$parent` to the console and inspect the DOM object there is a property `topicDiscovery.name`. However, when I try to log this (`$scope.$parent.topicDiscovery.name`) it returns `undefined`.

Also, when I try to log the `topicDiscovery` object it returns an empty array, even though when its not empty in the DOM for `$scope.$parent`.

Why is this?

Comment: What is the property name? `topicDiscovery` or `$topicDiscovery` ?

Comment: can you add jsfiddle demo

Comment: Some usual confusion with scopes. Use proper scope inheritance and avoid $parent. Or try to create a demo, otherwise it's not easy to guess and help.

Comment: @ShuhelAhmed it's `topicDiscovery`, I miss typed it in the question

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score -1):

This means `$scope.$parent.topicDiscovery` is getting changed after `console.log`. Google chrome doesnot print all json object when you do console.log. It just refer to current Object. Try using `JSON.stringify($scope.$parent)`, Here you will not get this property as stringify converts that JS object to string and there will not be any memory linking between orignal object and string.

Here is best example.

```js
var d={z:{b:{}}};

console.log(d); //When you check here, d.a_1 is available
console.log("d.a_1",d.a); //Here d.a_1 is not available.

//Here I am adding d.a_1 property
for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
  d['a_'+i]=i;
}
```

Comment: Angular's `$scope` behaves differently than normal JS objects do.

Comment: @Cerbrus, Browser console memory operation doesnt know whether it is angular or ember. If you render that value in view, then only you can get live updates of that variable.

Comment: @Cerbrus, Its shallow copy of object in console.log code internally. Please go through code Which I posted, and try using similar code with angular, you will get same result.

Comment: Child scopes in angular have access to their parents' properties. That isn't possible in normal JS.

Comment: @Cerbrus, Yes but the question is, He can get the object when He uses console.log($scope.$parent) and he gets undefined if he uses console.log($scope.$parent.topicDiscovery.name). What it means? Anyways angualrjs is madeup using vanilajs only. :)

Comment: My point is that your explanation on how object properties work is completely irrelevant here.